# Phone switches off while charging

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-note-3, power-on, shutdown

My Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo sometimes turns off automatically while charging on original wall charger. And then no physical button works, I have to remove the battery and then have to restart it. Anyone have any idea what might be the issue?